# Understanding JavaScript replace

Tags: javascript

I came across a piece of code like this:

```
btnHref.replace(/myCode=([^&]*)/, 'myCode=' + itm.MyCode);
```

I understand the replace function in general ([text to replace], [text to replace with])

However I do not quite understand what is going on with:

```
/myCode=([^&]*)/
```

It's looking for "myCode=", I'm assuming that the rest is a regular expression for any character after the '='.

However I am not getting my desired results..

Example:

```
var myParams = 'myCode=' + itm.ReportCode + '&myVersion=' + itm.ReportVersion;

if (btnHref.indexOf('myCode') > -1) {
    btnHref = btnHref.replace(/myCode=([^&]*)/, myParams);
} else {
    btnHref += btnHref.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' + myParams : '?' + myParams;
}
```

The first time through everything is good. (It hits the else statement)
However the second time through (it hits the first statement in the if) and I end up with a string of:

```
/MyController/MyAction?myCode=AAA&myVersion=1.1&myVersion=2.2
```

Am I misunderstanding what the regular expression is?

Comment: This is a great example of why you should *never* use regular expressions when you really need a parser. [Query strings are more nuanced than they might seem](http://zzzzbov.com/blag/querystring-hell), so I always recommend using a parsing library. [I wrote one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystringjs), although there are many others available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^&]*` matches any sequence of characters except `&`. So it replaces everything starting with `myCode=` up to, but not including, the first `&`. When you do it the second time, it leaves the part of `btnHref` after `&myVersion=2.2` alone. As a result, you end up with two `&myVersion=` parameters, because you're inserting another one.

That replacement is intended to replace *just* the `myCode` parameter, not any others. You should use a separate operation to replace `myVersion`.

```js
var newCode = 'myCode=code123';
var newVersion = 'myVersion=Version1.2';

var btnHref = '/MyController/MyAction';

if (btnHref.indexOf('myCode') > -1) {
    btnHref = btnHref.replace(/myCode=([^&]*)/, newCode);
} else {
    btnHref += btnHref.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' + newCode : '?' + newCode;
}
if (btnHref.indexOf('myVersion') > -1) {
    btnHref = btnHref.replace(/myVersion=([^&]*)/, newVersion);
} else {
    btnHref += btnHref.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' + newVersion : '?' + newVersion;
}
console.log(btnHref);

var newCode = 'myCode=codeXXX';
var newVersion = 'myVersion=Version2.2';

var btnHref = '/MyController/MyAction';

if (btnHref.indexOf('myCode') > -1) {
    btnHref = btnHref.replace(/myCode=([^&]*)/, newCode);
} else {
    btnHref += btnHref.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' + newCode : '?' + newCode;
}
if (btnHref.indexOf('myVersion') > -1) {
    btnHref = btnHref.replace(/myVersion=([^&]*)/, newVersion);
} else {
    btnHref += btnHref.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' + newVersion : '?' + newVersion;
}
console.log(btnHref);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  That makes it a clearer understanding now.